# How to pass to a POST controller action method the model, including the contents of a List object member property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit

I have a Razor page in which a controller GET action method returns the model to the view. That model contains a member which is a

```
List<int> ids
```

Now I want to call a POST method on the controller when I submit that page, passing the model, but it is not passing the contents of that `List<int> ids` member, as I always get an empty List.

I have even put hidden fields like this on the view, inside the form:

```
@foreach (var id in model.ids)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ids, new{ @name= "ids", @value = id})
}
```

Now I get an `null` `List` instead.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will generate value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The ids field is required." id="ids" name="ids" type="hidden" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" />
```

`Html.HiddenFor` returns an HTML hidden input element for each property in the object that is represented by the specified expression, using the specified HTML attributes. `Html.HiddenFor` is designed for only one value.  Th follow options make model binding  work correctly and pick up all of your hidden values in the list.

Try the code like :

**Option 1:**

```
 @foreach (var id in Model.ids)
 {      
       <input name="ids" type="hidden" value="@id" />
 }
```

**Option 2:**

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ids.Count; i++)
  {
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ids[i])
  }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I already tried the 2. option before my posting, and it didn't work. I receive null at the action method on the member. Perhaps you didn't understand that my case is a bit different, I pass the entire model to the Post method, where the List of ids is a member of such model.

Comment: Hi @sergiol   " I pass the entire model to the Post method, where the List of ids is a member of such model" I can get it,  have a look at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZodD.png

Comment: thanks. I have based part of my answer on yours.

Comment: You are welcome :).Glad it can help.

Answer (score 1):

So, based in @Qing Guo's answer I reverted my `@foreach` loop to an `@int` indexed `@for`.

I was in the track to append a `string idsText` member to my model with a comma-separated sequence with all the ids, and I noticed I was also receiving a null value.

So, it turns out I did something wrong:

```
List<int> ids;
string idsText;
```

I forgot to put `{get; set;}`

```
List<int> ids {get; set;}
string idsText {get; set;}
```

Then, with the `@foreach` I began to have generated code like

```
<input id="ids" name="ids" type="hidden" value="97424" />
<input id="ids" name="ids" type="hidden" value="97424" />
```

So, the value is the same for both entries, which is wrong.

When I reverted back to an indexed `@for`, the code generated was like:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="ids_0_" name="ids[0]" type="hidden" value="97424" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="ids_1_" name="ids[1]" type="hidden" value="97625" />
```

where both numbers are correct.

Then I began to got the `List<int> ids` member correctly fulfilled on the POST action method. And I could get rid of the

<s>string idsText {get; set};</s>

property, as the list member does its job well.